# Color vs Colors in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm writing a function in flutter like this

```
Expanded playButton({Color colorName, int buttonNumber, int soundNumber}) {
  return Expanded(
    child: FlatButton(
      color: colorName,
      onPressed: () {
        final player = AudioCache();
        player.play('note$soundNumber.wav');
      },
      child: Text(
        '> PLAY $buttonNumber',
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 35.0,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Why the argument should be ***Color colorName*** instead of ***Colors colorName***.
As we use ***color: Colors.teal*** for defining color.

Answer (score 0):

I think the class `Colors` is a programmer friendly wrapper of the `Color` class.
As you can see in the source code of the `Colors` class:

```dart
class Colors {
  // This class is not meant to be instatiated or extended; this constructor
  // prevents instantiation and extension.
  // ignore: unused_element
  Colors._();

  /// Completely invisible.
  static const Color transparent = Color(0x00000000);

...
}
```

Here the 'Colors' class defines a variable `transparent` which we could easily use like

```dart
...
Container(
      color: Colors.transparent,
)
...
```

So you always use a `Color` instance for a 'color' and therefore you have to define the variable as a `Color` instance, even if you use the `Colors` class wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Colors are predefined instances of the class Color.

It's like this...
Colors is to Color as Mercedes is to Car.  Not every Car is a Mercedes.  And not every Color object is a Colors object.

Btw, you can use Color to get the exact color you want, like...

```
const color = const Color(0xffb74093);
```

So it's much more versatile than Colors